# Cyclostationary time series parameter estimation

Tags: time-series, estimation, references, stationarity

I'm looking for resources (articles, books or just suggestions) on cyclostationary time series parameter estimation. I have a 2D signal of that sort, which forms a grid.

Comment: Is it atmospheric data? http://books.google.se/books?id=fxPiH9Ef9VoC&printsec=frontcover&dq=inauthor:%22Daniel+S.+Wilks%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zq-qULvlFamE4gSkwIHQCQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @gerrit, it's actually neuronal data so there's not much literature on cyclostationary series applied to neuroscience. Any tips if I should go with the cyclostationary approach or use directional (circular) statistics?